# Copy to Cliboard - Multiple items

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add `myInput2` and so on to this page, but I am not sure how to properly do that in the Javascript section. When I try to add `myInput2` it works, but it also makes `myInput` not work. How do I have multiple sections of text that I can make it easy for people to copy what is in the form?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" value="hello word" id="myInput"><button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>

        <br><br>

        <input type="text" value="Hello World 2" id="myInput2">
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text 2</button>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
                
                copyText.select();
                copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
                document.execCommand("copy");

                alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It isn't clear what exactly you are trying to do. How does something work and not work at the same time? Please edit your question so that It is more clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [previousElementSibling](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_previouselementsibling.asp) to select the element before the button that was clicked:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <input type="text" value="hello word" id="myInput"><button onclick="myFunction(event)">Copy text</button>

  <br><br>

  <input type="text" value="Hello World 2" id="myInput2">
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)">Copy text 2</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction(event) {
      var copyText = event.target.previousElementSibling;
      copyText.select();
      copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
      document.execCommand("copy");
      alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```